# Chrome Extensions - Send messages to external page not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome app and i'm trying to send a message to an external webpage. In the whole scenario, the external webpage needs to send a message back (but i'm not trying to achieve this yet).

Here is my code:

**background.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="background.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**background.js**

```
var FileMessage = "Hello!";
var scriptName = "script.js";
var tabID;

//open a new tab with an app
function openApp() {
var url = "link_to_external_webpage_on_personal_server";
var win = window.open(url);
}

//function to run js files inside the extension
function runScript(script){
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: script});
}

//function to send a message to all tabs
function sendMessage(){
chrome.tabs.query({'active': true}, function(tabs) {
    if(tabs.length === 1){
        var tab = tabs[0];
        //var tabID = tab.id;
        chrome.extension.sendMessage(null, {newMessage : FileMessage}); 
        console.log("extension sent a message...");
    }
});
}

//main()
$(document).ready(function() {
openApp();
//when a new tab is updated
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
        //createEvent();
        sendMessage();
    }
});
});

/*function createEvent(){

    $.event.trigger({
    type: "newMessage",
    message: "Hello World!"
    });
}*/
```

**external js file**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log( "app script is running" );

  $(document).on("newMessage", newMessageHandler);

  /*document.addEventListener("myEvent",myEventHandler);*/

  document.addEventListener("newMessage",myEventHandler);

  document.addEventListener('newMessage', function(event) {
  console.log("message received...");
}, false);

});
```

I can see that most of the code is running with the console prints. The only one i'm not receiving is the one saying "message received". I've also tried using events (commented in the code) but i was not successful too.

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance for the help !

Comment: Are you trying to send messages to web-pages that are open by your extension programmatically or also by the user ?

Comment: The pages are opened programmatically `var url = "link_to_external_webpage_on_personal_server";
var win = window.open(url);`

Comment: I finally found a way to do it using events and window.postmessage ! If needed i can post the solution i've found.

Comment: You beat me to it :) You are always welcome (encouraged actually) to post the answer to any question (even the ones you posted yourself), so other people who may land on this page facing a similar problem will benefit as well.